# .htaccess inconsistent results

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a RewriteRule that works fine on my local server, but when I upload to a test server, the rule stops working and gives a 'not found' error.

```
RewriteRule ^/?id/name/([^.]+)/?$ id/name/index.php?details=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm trying to get the query string to work on the same page whilst maintaining a directory like url. e.g. website.com/id/name?details=dob will look like website.com/id/name/dob

On the test server I'm using a subdomain, whilst on my local server I'm just using localhost.

Comment: Anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Sure the test server has `mod_rewrite` enabled and `AllowOverride` set to `All`?

Comment: Your rewrite rule must never work because it does not receive leading slash

Comment: What error are you getting on test server? Is it 404? Where is this htaccess located?